# Why 0 has been added after 15th digit in excel and how to have the actual data

Tags: excel

I have copied a 17 digit data from notepad to excel. The text got converted to scientific notation. When I double clicked on it I can see the actual numbers  upto 15 digits.But 0 has been placed in 16th and 17th digit. How can we change that to have actual digits.

For Eg: 12345678901234567 is copied from notepad to excel.

1.23457E+16 appeared after copying. When I double clicked on it,

I could see 123456789012345**00**.How can I overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

That is because an Excel value can only carry 15 digits.

See:

[15 Digits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/269370)

**EDIT#1:**

To overcome this, format the cell to *Text* before copying the data.

**EDIT#2:**

I tried with your example from your post as follows:

- format a cell as *Text*
- high-light your example in Chrome and copied with <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>
- **click in the Formula Bar**
- touch <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>

The result:

[image]

***If you do not click in the Formula Bar, you will loose digits.***

Comment: Could u please tell me how to have the actual data bro?

Comment: @Ragav  See  my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: But the 16th and 17th digit remains 0 even then..what should be done for getting the actual digits as I mentioned in example

Comment: Can you tell me bro ..how to have data in text type as default and not in scientific notation while typing a big numeric value